# Definition of emissivity?

Tags: thermodynamics, definition, radiation

A have come across a definition of emissivity which is along the following lines:

> Emissivity is the power emitted per solid angle per frequency per surface area.

This definition, however seems very different from the common ones found e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity) which are to do with ratio of such as radiance with those of a black body. Is the definition I have given above a common definition for emissivity, and if so why the difference in the two definitions?

Comment: is it emissivity or emissive power? the definition sounds like the later one's..

Comment: @BruceLee That is my felling, however I this definition was definitely for emissivity.

Comment: still please check it..

Comment: @BruceLee here is the source: *Fundamentals of statistical and thermal physics* by Reif, F. international ed, 1985, pg382 section 9.25

Comment: "power per solid angle per frequency" is easily converted to "power per solid angle per wavelength" .  However, I agree that emissivity should be defined in terms of the temperature as well, as that affects the total power per unit frequency (not just the shift in the peak frequency).

Comment: It's a mistake. I think this book also deals with other matters in a rather loose way (statement based on my memory of using it as an undergraduate and deciding it was not quite careful enough IMO).

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed an error. Emissivity is the emission relative to that of a black body of the same temperature.